# Automatic Reference Counting off,

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am using xcode 4.2
I am using some libraries in my project which shows error on "release" so i turned off the ARC.

My application is working fine, but now in my project i nowhere used release of any object, so my objects are still in memory or released?

Answer (score 0):

They are still in memory and are leaked.  Use Instruments to help find all the leaks.

Comment: i checked in instrument in leak the memory keeps on increasing when i more explore my application views. What should i do to clean the memory , coz i am new to xcode, and i have been using ARC before, in dealloc method what should i dealloc before super dealloc, its a dynamic app having tableviews fetching data from web services

Comment: @mindFreezer you shouldn’t `dealloc` anything (ever!) except for `super` in your implementation of `dealloc`. What you need to do is `release` objects you _own_ when you don’t need them anymore and `retain` them when you have to hold on to them. Please read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and use the static analyzer in Xcode.